# Sqlite3 equivalent queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

The first query is returning the expected rows but the 2nd one isn't returning anything

```
select * 
from posts 
where (date <= date('now')) and (date >= date('now', '-1 month'))

select * 
from posts 
where date between date('now') and date('now', '-1 month')
```

Aren't they supposed to be equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your end expression comes before your begin expression.  Try this:

```
select * from posts where date between date('now', '-1 month') and date('now')
```

Comment: Yep. From the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#between): _The BETWEEN operator is logically equivalent to a pair of comparisons. "x BETWEEN y AND z" is equivalent to "x>=y AND x<=z"_